# How do I show ☺♦♦ characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, unicode-string

You can I display special Unicode characters in my result set on my SQL Server?

e.g. How can i display those characters `☺♦♦`?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. I tried to provide you an answer, but I'm not sure if it's that what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well due to the fact that your question is very unspecific here are some solutions.

You need to specify a string as unicode string. This can be achieved by adding an `N` in front of the string. See example:

```
SELECT N'☺♦♦' as a, '☺♦♦' as b
```

Result:

```
a    b
---- ----
☺♦♦  ???
```

If you want to store those symbols, you need a type as `nvarchar` or `nchar`.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: No problemo. Nice that it helped you.

Comment: @MaheshwaranRagunathan: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.